# How can I format a "vertical" vector with curly braces around it?

Tags: output-formatting

Beginners question. I am trying to get mathematica to format my Stirling number formulas using curly braces [image] instead of [image] (sorry for the images).  This is just for display purposes so it does not have to be linked to StirlingS2. I have the same question for square brackets (for the stirling numbers of the first kind)

Comment: Please take a [**tour**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how to express your appreciation via upvotes and an accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Custom output-formatting is one way:

```
MakeBoxes[StirlingS2[n_, k_], StandardForm] := 
 RowBox[{
   "{", 
   GridBox[{{"n"}, {"k"}}, AutoDelete -> False, 
    GridBoxItemSize -> {"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}}],
   "}"}]

StirlingS2[n, k]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

If for display only, another option is using `Matex`. Here are two versions, one for curly and one for solid braces.

```
<< MaTeX`
stirling1[n_,k_]:=MaTeX["{"<>ToString[n]<>"\\brace "<>ToString[k]<>"}",Magnification->2]
stirling2[n_,k_]:=MaTeX["{"<>ToString[n]<>"\\brack "<>ToString[k]<>"}",Magnification->2]
```

And now

```
stirling1[n,k]
stirling2[n,k]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 Grid[Table[
  Row[{stirling1[n, k], stirling2[n, k]}], {n, 1, 5}, {k, 6, 10}], Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

The `Notation` package can work very well for this.  I would suggest you read the documentation as it allows you to input your notation in a friendly and intuitive form, whose appearance does not survive cut and paste to this website.  (Though it should work functionally)

```
Needs["Notation`"]

Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{"{", 
GridBox[{{"n_"}, {"k_"}}], "}"}]] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] 
ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{"StirlingS2", "[", 
RowBox[{"n_", ",", "k_"}], "]"}]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
Subscript[\[ScriptCapitalS], n] // Superscript[#, (\[ScriptK])] &
% // FullForm
{{n, k} // TableForm}
% // FullForm
```

Out:

[image]